# general way to find parent version from dependent product

Tags: jboss, version, wildfly, data-analysis

is there any generally way to figure out parent version from its child  for example ***jetty:***** match with which version of java or another one ***Wild-Fly:***** match with which `J-boss` version
thanks for your answers

Comment: Can you give some context as to where you are searching for the "product"?

Comment: I wanna find products in a specific ip and relative cves
generally the products are depend on other. for example  jboss EAP, jetty and etc  depend on java 
now for example  if i have jboss EAP version , can we find version of java running on that sever?

Comment: That would need to be checked at the OS level. JBoss EAP does require Java, but it doesn't ship with a JVM.